# If I write an entire system based on Magento2, can I sell it to another individual?

Tags: magento2, overrides, licensing, billing-agreements, license

Based on Magento2 license agreement, if I write an entire system based on Magento2 platform, will it be considered as my legal property and can I sell my entire system to another individual ?

Currently, we are working on an enterprise level ecommerce solution based on Magento2 platform. We are making hundreds of extensions that overriding Magento's core functionalities without editing the core files, and just by overriding using well-written Magento2 extensions. We are not touching Magento2, and we don't sell/change/add/modify/rename it.

One of our concerns is its license and our business exit strategy: If we build our entire software based on Magento2 as its base platform and core of our software, will it be considered as our own property and not Magento's property ? Our business owner concern is that if we build it based on Magento2, it will be considered as Magento's property and it won't be ours and it will be too dangerous for his business.

But I think if we build extensions for Magento, there is no place in the agreement that confirms its extensions is not Magento's property. I think we shouldn't write the entire software from the beginning to consider it as our own property, right ? Am I missing something?

Comment: You need a lawyer, this is not considered a community question IMO.

Comment: @Michael, post here once : http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "We are making hundreds of extensions that overriding Magento's core functionalities", whats so special about the functionality of the "hundreds" of extensions you're creating that Magento core code can't do? Give me a few examples. Because in my opinion thats very a silly thing to do without having the right reasons and even if there was a reason for doing that why not look at other platforms out there?